# Django friendship in messages compose

Tags: django, django-forms, django-apps

I am using django-friends and django-messages.

I have modified my custom compose form to pull the following information, myfriends and also display their fullnames instead of just usernames.

One problem I have is that I cannot seem to access myself as a signed in user, to complete the query, I have to hard code it.

```
class MyComposeForm(forms.Form):
    """
    A simple default form for private messages.
    """
    recipient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Friendship.objects.all(), label=_(u"Recipient"))
    #recipient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), label=_(u"Recipient"))
    subject = forms.CharField(label=_(u"Subject"))
    body = forms.CharField(label=_(u"Body"),
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '2', 'cols':'55'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        recipient_filter = kwargs.pop('recipient_filter', None)
        super(MyComposeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ### underneath here I have to hardcode with my ID to pull the info.
        friends = Friendship.objects.filter(from_user=1)
        self.fields['recipient'].choices = [(friend.to_user.pk, friend.to_user.get_full_name()) for friend in friends]
        if recipient_filter is not None:
            self.fields['recipient']._recipient_filter = recipient_filter
```

How do I access my user instance?

I have tried adding `request` to `__init__` and using `request.user` but this does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass request in your form like:

```
form = MyComposeForm(request.POST,request)
```

in your views.py file, where the form has been instantiated. You can then access the request object as:

```
requestObj = kwargs.pop('request', None)
```

your code will look like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    recipient_filter = kwargs.pop('recipient_filter', None)
    requestObj = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(MyComposeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```